# Why is getPointerCount() always returning 1?

Tags: android, multi-touch

An experiment in learning Android is to detect two-finger presses. I have an app that changes a custom ImageView to a random pic on a touch. That works fine. I now want it to only change the picture when two or more fingers press. I have an IF statement to only randomize the picture if pointerCount>1. It doesn't do anything.

I have my ASUS Transformer TF101 connected to the PC. I have a simple custom ImageView with an onTouch event.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int number =event.getPointerCount();
    if (number > 1){
        *randomise pic*
```

I examine the value of 'number' during a debug step-through (Log.d doesn't work for me from this ASUS :() and it's always 1 no matter how many fingers I touch with.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you return **true** in this method?

Comment: No. I had just found that - noob mistake :D
I still returned the super() form. This question can be closed.

Answer (score -3):

(X) return false;

(X)  return super.onTouchEvent(event);

(O) return true;

Comment: What exactly is this answering?